# pause a Thread inside a current thread

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i create a form and inside was  created a method that i trying calling as a different thread, and i want to pause for a 2 second and start again. but the problem is, when i add thread.sleep.(1000), this its freezing my form thread instead of the another thread.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
     new Thread(() => Application.Run(new DrawForm())).Start();
}

public partial class DrawForm : Form
{
   private void CallToRun(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (menu.option == 1)
      {
          while (true)
          {
             Thread t1 = new Thread(() => MyMethod());
             t1.Start();
             Thread.Sleep(2000)//but this stop my current thread and not my MyMethod()
         }
      }
   }

  private void MyMethod()
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Runing....")
  }
}
```

should be somethings like that: 
runing
1..
2..
runing
1
2
runing

Comment: MyMethod should call Sleep, not the main thread.

Comment: I suggest you to read about Winform GUI thread and worker threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems here.

1. There is no need to start your form in another thread, and could have unexpected consiquences
2. You are on  the UI thread, you give your work to another thread and you are pausing the UI thread thread and blocking the message pump... hrmm.
3. Why are you using Thread? Get with the millennium and use Tasks
4. This could possibly be `async` and `await`. However, lets put that aside for now

**Program.cs**

```
// lets start normally 
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   Application.Run(new DrawForm ());
}
```

The easiest this to do would be

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => 
{
    MyMethod();
    Thread.Sleep(2000); //pausing the right thread
);
```

However you could do this

```
private void CallToRun(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // runs concurrently
   Task.Run(
      () =>
         {
            while (true) // woah are you sure you want to run this forever?
            {
               MyMethod();

               //doesn't pause the message pump
               Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
         });

}
```

However in the modern world we might use `async` and `await` pattern in one of its various forms

**Example**

```
private async Task CallToRun(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   while (true) // woah this stil smells
   {
      MyMethod();
      await Task.Delay(2000); // not pausing the message pump, yay
   }
}
```